# Java Loading ints from seperate classes universally

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Okay so I am coding a program right now that takes information from a JTextField, and would multiply it by a certain amount, based on what the double is set to in the class that's set up with that button. When the button is clicked, I'd like to retrieve an int from the class file that it's assigned to. But I want to assign them universally. It's really hard to explain, but basically right now I have to hard code them all. this is the current code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println("Clicked: " + getButtonName());

    if (Settings.SelectedChamp == "Aatrox") {

        TestFrame.PNameField.setText(ChampionScales.PNameAatrox);
        TestFrame.QNameField.setText(ChampionScales.QNameAatrox);
        try {
            int QMath = (int) Double.parseDouble(TestFrame.AttackDamageField.getText());
            System.out.println(ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[0] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[1] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[2] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[3] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[4] + "(+" + QMath
                    * 0.6 + ")");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            int QMath = 0;
            System.out.println(ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[0] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[1] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[2] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[3] + "/"
                    + ChampionScales.QBaseDamageAatrox[4] + "(+" + QMath
                    * 0.6 + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Here I made it so that if you click Aatrox's button, it'd do the math and type it all into the Console. But I also have an entire class set up just for these ints. here: `

```
public class Aatrox 
{
    public static String PName = "Blood Well";

    public String QName = "Dark Flight";
    public int QBaseDamage[] = { 70, 115, 160, 205, 250 };
    public double QScalingAD = .6;
    public double QScalingAP = 0;
    public String QADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String WName = "Blood Thirst";
    public int WBaseDamage[] = { 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 };
    public double WScalingAD = 1;
    public double WScalingAP = 0;
    public String WADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String W2Name = "Blood Price";
    public int W2BaseDamage[] = { 60, 95, 130, 165, 200 };
    public double W2ScalingAD = 1;
    public double W2ScalingAP = 0;
    public String W2ADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String EName = "Blades of Torment";
    public int EBaseDamage[] = { 75, 110, 145, 180, 215 };
    public double EScalingAD = .6;
    public double EScalingAP = .6;
    public String EADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String RName = "Massacre";
    public int RBaseDamage[] = { 200, 300, 400 };
    public double RScalingAD = 0;
    public double RScalingAP = 1;
    public String RADDamageStyle = null;

}
```

So I want to be able to make a file just like this for every champion, and keep all the same names. The problem is.. how would I call that champion's ints and stuff without having to hardcode `Aatrox.QScalingAD(); or Teemo.EScalingAP();`? how could I just do it universally? Thanks for the help. I've been stumped haha. `

Answer (score 0):

```
    You make a base class which you fill with your common stuff:

class BaseClass
{
    public static String PName = "Blood Well";

    public String QName = "Dark Flight";
    public int QBaseDamage[] = { 70, 115, 160, 205, 250 };
    public double QScalingAD = .6;
    public double QScalingAP = 0;
    public String QADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String WName = "Blood Thirst";
    public int WBaseDamage[] = { 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 };
    public double WScalingAD = 1;
    public double WScalingAP = 0;
    public String WADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String W2Name = "Blood Price";
    public int W2BaseDamage[] = { 60, 95, 130, 165, 200 };
    public double W2ScalingAD = 1;
    public double W2ScalingAP = 0;
    public String W2ADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String EName = "Blades of Torment";
    public int EBaseDamage[] = { 75, 110, 145, 180, 215 };
    public double EScalingAD = .6;
    public double EScalingAP = .6;
    public String EADDamageStyle = "Bonus";

    public String RName = "Massacre";
    public int RBaseDamage[] = { 200, 300, 400 };
    public double RScalingAD = 0;
    public double RScalingAP = 1;
    public String RADDamageStyle = null;
}

class Aatrox extends BaseClass 
{
    //Do Aatrox-specific stuff here!
}

class xyz extends BaseClass 
{
    //Do xyz-specific stuff here
}
```

with 'extends' both Aatrox and xyz have ALL the functions of the class `BaseClass`.

Comment: So I came up with an idea. Here written is an example:

   System.out.println("ChampionScales.QBaseDamage" + ButtonName + "[1]");

is there anyway, if I made the contents of the printline message into a string, could I convert a string to a line of code?